# How to make iFrame responsive in iPhone 6

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, iframe

I have added an iframe and it is working fine in all browsers and some devices but in iphone 6. The iframe is not responsive. It does not fit 100% of iphone screen size.

I found many solutions online but most of them showed how to make an iFrame scroll in iphone. I dont need that. I want to make it responsive and adjust according to screen size.

```
<div class="frame-container" style="position: relative; padding-bottom: 65.25%; padding-top: 30px; height: 0;">
<iframe id="frame" width="100%" height="1000px" style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe >
</div>
```

I have removed the src="" in iframe in the sample above

Comment: did you try to put the height to `100vh`??

Comment: no, I have never used this before. What does this do and where do I have to put this, in iFrame or div?

Comment: instead of `height="1000px"` put `height="100vh"`so the height become related to the view port which mean your iframe height will be the same as the height of the page

Comment: what about the width? Right now the iframe's width is not within the iphone s6 viewport. How do I make that responsive?

Comment: actually i can't imagine how the iframe looks on iphone can you give me a screen shot ?

Answer (score 0):

We can set padding-bottom to 75%. So need to give height for that, because Padding bottom will manage the height.
And We do not set the width because it will automatically resize with the responsive element.
Setting "overflow" to "hidden" ensures that any content protruding outside of this element.

If suppose will not align properly then will try with //"iframe{max-width:100%;}"